Add custom text for each theme in Laravel?
I have a Laravel application. Let's say we have a form with 3 input fields and 3 labels. Let's also say that we have 100 themes, and each client/theme wants custom text for the labels. So the inputs are the same, only the text in the labels are different.
For example.
Theme 1 wants: Polls and Quizzes, Theme 2 wants: My Polls and Quizzes, Theme 3 wants: Polls, Theme 4 wants: Quizzes, etc...
Let's also say that our website is bilingual.
Right now, we're saving the fields in the database with english and french column names, but if we have thousands of fields which we want to be customizable, what is the best way to go about this, because saving thousands of text columns names in the database doesn't seem like the right answer here.
IMPORTANT NOTE:
We're trying to have a WordPress style application when it comes to theming.
I understand that there are Theming packages in Laravel, and we're using one (qiro lab themer laravel), but it only talks about handling assets, and not how to handle multilingual text for each of those themes. P.S. I see now that there are more popular/better Laravel Theming packages out there, and I'll look into those.
MY QUESTION IS ABOUT THE LOCALIZATION
I'm sure that I'm missing something, it is possible to have multiple resources/lang/ folders for each theme? What's the best approach here?

If this is using Laravel blade/livewire/tall stack, then start with https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Though text and its translation are saved as php files. Meaning you would need to commit the lang files or create a piece of code that will write php files dynamically.

As for adding theme (theme 1 en, theme 2 en, theme 1 fr, theme 2 fr) etc, you would would need to separate the lang files by language then by themes. (en/fr both have theme 1 and theme 2). Dont forget to add fallback lang.

Last, add a condition in your blade files which lang on which theme you want to display your text. I suggest to create a helper class for this like LocaleText::translate('text.translation').

On my earlier comment write the code to generate php files (can no longer update ccomment), if these text are saved in database, create a Command file that will generate the PHP files based on the values of your db. Then execute this once or every time someone saves in the db. This will be a slightly big feature.

On my other earlier comment (adding helper class), maybe save the theme-key as env or session.
